# Eclipse JavaScript code formatter and JSHint anonymous function format conflict

Tags: eclipse, anonymous-function, jslint, formatter, jsdt

I am using the Eclipse (version Indigo) JavaScript code formatter and using the [jshint-eclipse](http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/) plugin  with **white: true** option for code convention validation.

Eclipse code formatter and JSHint plugin conflict with the anonymous function declaration format.
The JavaScript code formatter formats anonymous functions like the following:

```
var f1 = function() {
};
```

But the jshint-eclipse plugin gives a "Missing spaces after function" warning.
The right format for this plugin is:

```
var f1 = function () {
};
```

NOTE THE SPACE AFTER THE function

Is there a way to format anonymus function declaration differently with eclipse than regular function declarations. I would like to add one space after "function" for anonymous functions but not for normal functions.

Thanks.

**Update** a relevang eclipse bug is [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=315507)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug for this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=315507

Similar bug in Aptana was fixed: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3792

I've worked out a patch for this: https://github.com/eclipse/webtools.jsdt.core/pull/1
which hopefully will be merged and released soon.

Answer (score -2):

Check the JavaScript formatting preferences (Preference->JavaScript->Code Style->Formatter) on the White Space tab, for the Declarations of Functions.

Comment: Thanks for answering nitind. I checked that but there is no way to set the declaration formatting separately for anonymous function declaration and regular function declaration.